# Elements disappearing on top responsive react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am developing a responsive webapp using react. The width is correct when cropping, but when cropping vertically, the elements on top disappear and I can't scroll to see them. I have set the parent component and the actual container with 100vh height. I don't know how to make the elements not to disappear. Here I show what I am talking about.

[Normal webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ1WT.png)

[Webpage when I crop vertically, searchbar is hidden and I can't access it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGqID.png)

Navbar code:

```css
.fixed-top-nav {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}

  <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md" fixed="top" className="fixed-top-nav">
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">Tweet Classifier</Navbar.Brand>
       <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
         <Nav className="container-fluid">
         </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
```

RouterComponent:

```
Router>
        <NavbarComponent></NavbarComponent>
        <Switch>
          <div className="background">
            <Route exact path={["/"]} component={HomeComponent} />
            <Route
              exact
              path={["/domains"]}
              component={DomainsComponent}
            />{" "}
            <Route
              exact
              path={["/tweets/:domain"]}
              component={TweetsComponent}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path={["/editdomain/:domainId"]}
              component={EditDomainComponent}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path={["/createdomain"]}
              component={CreateDomainComponent}
            />
            <Route exact path={["/edituser"]} component={EditUserComponent} />
            <Route exact path={["/about"]} component={AboutComponent} />
            <Route
              exact
              path={["/evalTweet/:tweetId"]}
              component={EvaluateTweetComponent}
            />
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Background css (acts like body):

```
.background {
  background-image: url("../images/background.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center; /* NEW */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Domain component (the one I showed pictures of):

```
 <Container className="contenedor" fluid="md">
        <Col sm="auto" md="auto" className="columna">
          <Row
            sm="auto"
            className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column fila"
          >
            <InputGroup className="mb-3" id="buscar">
              <Form.Control
                placeholder="Busca un dominio"
                aria-label="Busca un dominio"
                aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
                onChange={onChangeSearchDomain}
                value={searchDomain}
                id="input"
              />
              <Button variant="light" id="button-addon2" onClick={findByDomain}>
                Buscar
              </Button>
            </InputGroup>{" "}
          </Row>
          {currentDomains.map((domain, index) => (
            <Row sm="auto" key={domain._id}>
              <Card className="custom-card-domain">
                <Card.Header as="h5" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  {domain.name}
                  <Dropdown id="opciones">
                    <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light">
                      <IoOptions size={25} />
                    </Dropdown.Toggle>
                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                      <Dropdown.Item href={`/editdomain/${domain._id}`}>
                        Editar
                      </Dropdown.Item>
                      <Dropdown.Item
                        onClick={() => {
                          if (
                            window.confirm(
                              "¿Seguro que desea eliminar el dominio?"
                            )
                          )
                            deleteDomain(domain._id);
                        }}
                      >
                        Eliminar
                      </Dropdown.Item>
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                  </Dropdown>
                </Card.Header>
                <Card.Body className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column h-100">
                  <Card.Text>{domain.description}</Card.Text>
                  <Card.Text>
                    <strong>Hashtags:</strong> {domain.hashtags.join(" ")}{" "}
                  </Card.Text>
                  <Button href={`/tweets/${domain._id}`}>Acceder</Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Row>
          ))}
          <Row
            sm="auto"
            className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column fila"
          >
            <Pagination
              className="pagination"
              count={totalPages}
              page={page}
              onChange={pageChanged}
            />
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </Container>
```

Container css:

```
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Please also provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example[(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what your code is doing. It seems you need to apply some margin top to "bump" the page down when displaying the top menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a reproducible code it would be great but it seems like your `Navbar` has a `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` and that's why your elements are beneath it.
If your `container` is at `100vh`, I would advise you for you to center your content with

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

If this doesn't make sense, please provide some code so I can give a better answer

Comment: Thanks! I already did that but doesn't work. I have just updated the question with code.